# Getting null value in one column with "findById" in Java Spring although it exists in DB

Tags: java, angular, spring, jpa

I am very new in Java Spring and have a problem where I can not figure out what am I missing.

For the shake of brevity I will make it short:

- I have a controller class with two methods for @GetMapping (get info from a patient in database) and @PostMapping (upload a photo from that patient).
- In both methods, at some point I am calling through "findById" to database and populating a "Patient" model class object.
- All the attributes of this class are retrieved successfully from Database but there is an attribute of this class (getPhoto()) that gets a null value only in the @PostMapping method.
- What am I missing? The code is just the same in both methods.

Thanks very much in advance!!

Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/patients"})
public class PatientController {

    @Autowired
    IPatientService patientService;


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> listPatientId(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){

        Optional<Patient> patient=null;
        Map<String, Object> response=new HashMap<>();

        try{
            patient=patientService.findById(id);
        }catch(DataAccessException e){
            response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": "+e.getMostSpecificCause().toString()));
            new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        System.out.println("Patient with id: "+id+" / "+patient.get().getId()+" which photo is: "+patient.get().getPhoto());

        /*Some other code*/
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestParam("archive")MultipartFile archive, @RequestParam("id") Integer id){

        Optional<Paciente> paciente = Optional.empty();
        Map<String, Object> respuesta= new HashMap<>();

        try{
            patient=patientService.findById(id);
        }catch(DataAccessException e){
            response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": "+e.getMostSpecificCause().toString()));
            new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        System.out.println("Patient with id: "+id+" / "+patient.get().getId()+" which photo is: "+patient.get().getPhoto());

        /*Some other code*/

    }
}
```

Patient class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patients")
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String photo;

    (Getters and setters)
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, Integer> {

    Iterable<Patient> findByNameContainingOrSurnameContaining(String name, String surname);

}
```

Service (Interface and Implemantation):

```
public interface IPatientService {

    public List<Patient> findAll();

    public Optional<Patient> findById(Integer id);

    public Iterable<Patient> findByNameContainingOrSurnameContaining(String term);

 }



@Service
public class PatientServiceImpl implements IPatientService {

    @Autowired
    private PatientRepository patientDao; 


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Patient> findAll() {
        return patientDao.findAll();
    }


    @Override
    public Optional<Patient> findById(Integer id) {
        return patienteDao.findById(id);
    }

    public Iterable<Patient> findByNameContainingOrSurnameContaining(String term){
        return patientDao.findByNameContainingOrSurnameContaining(term, term);
    }

    @Override
    public Patient save(Patient patient){
        return patientDao.save(patient);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        patientDao.deleteById(id);
    }


}
```

As stated before, "patient.get().getPhoto()" returns in @GetMapping the actual value stored in the database. But in the method annotated with @PostMapping returns null for that value (Although other attributes seem to work just fine).

This was the backend, but in the frontend I am using Angular, where I call this method in component (I am showing just the parts involved in the uploading photo):

```
  patient: Patient;


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private service: ServiceServicee) {
    this.paient = new Patient();
  }


 uploadPhoto() {
    this.service.uploadPhoto(this.selectedPhoto, 
      this.patient.id).subscribe(patient => {
        this.patient = patient;
      });
  }
```

Service:

```
  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private router:Router) {
    this.urlPatients='http://localhost:8080/patients';
   }

uploadPhoto(file: File, id):Observable<Patient>{

     let formData= new FormData();
    

     formData.append("archive", file);
     formData.append("id", id);
     
     return this.http.post(`${this.urlPatients}/upload`, formData).pipe(
       map((response:any)=> response.patient as Patient),
       catchError(e=>{
         console.error(e.error.mensaje);
         return throwError(e);
       })
     );

   }
```

UPDATE:
Using Postman and making a POST to http://localhost:8080/patients/upload and sending in the body a jpg file (form-data - "archive") and a id number("id"), I got a success with the inserts and the method it didn't worked previously in the backend (patient.get().getPhoto()) worked perfectly this time. With the same code, so I assume that it is as @BiteBat said and it is a problem of the Frontend and how it is calling the Backend.

Comment: As a note, you can simply use `@PathVariable("id") Patient patient`. However, have you debugged your controller and ensured that the value of `id` is actually what you expect?

Comment: You miss 'return' statement in both catch block

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Yes, I made sure that the value id is right in both methods... Although return statement is missing in my example, in the actual code I have it present.

Answer (score 1):

I simulated the same environment that you created and it works for me as you expect, I leave the code for you to review what your problem. I would think you are incorrectly calling the POST method. Now, I would recommend that you do not save the images in a relational database, because there are alternatives with better performance, such as Google Storage / Local storage or any file storage service.

Structure:

[image]

EntryPoint:

```
package question;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class JulianPelayoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JulianPelayoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
package question.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import question.repository.Patient;
import question.repository.PatientsRepository;

@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/patients")
public class PatientController {

    private PatientsRepository patientsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PatientController(PatientsRepository patientsRepository) {
        this.patientsRepository = patientsRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> listPatientId(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){

        Optional<Patient> patient=null;
        Map<String, Object> response=new HashMap<>();

        try{
            patient = patientsRepository.findById(id);
        }catch(DataAccessException e){
            response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": "+e.getMostSpecificCause().toString()));
            new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        System.out.println("Patient with id: "+id+" / "+patient.get().getId()+" which photo is: "+patient.get().getPhoto());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(patient);
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestParam("archive") MultipartFile archive, @RequestParam("id") Integer id){

        Optional<Patient> patient = Optional.empty();
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

        try{
            patient = patientsRepository.findById(id);
        }catch(DataAccessException e){
            response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": "+e.getMostSpecificCause().toString()));
            new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        System.out.println("Patient with id: "+id+" / "+patient.get().getId()+" which photo is: "+patient.get().getPhoto());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(patient);

    }
    
}
```

Repository:

```
package question.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PatientsRepository extends CrudRepository<Patient, Integer>{

}
```

Patient:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patients", schema = "business")
@Getter @Setter
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String photo;
    
}
```

Spring.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>question</groupId>
    <artifactId>JulianPelayo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JulianPelayo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Response:

Get
[image]

Post
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response BiteBat. Although it was useful for me, I couldn't get my problem solved of getting the string name of the photo (patient.get().getPhoto()). I will keep working it through and as soon as I find my mistake, I will post it here. Thanks also for the recommendation!

Comment: Could you show us how you are consuming or calling the method? And you could also show the service class and the repository class, there might be errors in those classes too.

Comment: Sorry @BiteBat for my delayed response. I have edited again my question, inserting repository and service class. As well, as the part  in the frontend (Angular) calling the methods. I have used Postman and everything works perfectly, so I assume it is as you said and the problem is related to Angular and not the Java Spring code.